# Identifying the state of an application

Tags: c#, c, window, jna

Is there a way to obtain whether an application has loaded to a point where it requires user input? For example, if you're installing a program are you able to tell when it has finished and require the users interaction? E.g. Clicking finish or restart button.

Comment: Not the way the question is put. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi there, I'll try re-phrase that. Using an installation of a program as an example: - User runs setup.exe, then enters some settings (to configure program), after this there will be some point in which the program will begin to install. When the program has finished it may require the user to "Finish" or "Restart". Is it possible to detect when the installation has ended and is requiring the user to make some final action (e.g."Restart" or "Finish") ? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you can use the Installer.AfterInstall Event to write codes to be executed after the installation has finished. Look in the link below for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.afterinstall(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, are there any methods in Windows API that can do this? I am looking to map the method with Java Native Access to be able to use this in a Java project. Cheers